# onSwipeRefreshLayout - NullPointerException always

Tags: android

Why am I getting this error-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener
```

while implementing onSwipeRefreshLayout just like in the following example? http://javatechig.com/video/android-lollipop-swipe-to-refresh-example

The program crushes on `swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener`. I use a ViewPager but I don't know if it has anything to do with it.

You asked for a code, although I did mention that my implementation is similar to the one in the link I posted above:

**MainActivity**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.mySwipeRefreshLayout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            //...
        }
    });
```

**XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Retrieving Books..."
        android:id="@+id/textView_tabfragment_category"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/mySwipeRefreshLayout" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**I do want to have my SwipeRefreshLayout inside a RelativeLayout**.

Comment: Your SwipeRefreshLayout is null, please post your code and i will tell you why.

Comment: where is your code ??

Comment: Please read above.

Comment: arey you sure you're inflating the right layout xml ?

Comment: Like @MalekHijazi said, make sure your activity_main.xml contains the xml you provided in the question

Comment: Did you forget to call super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) ?